# Curl data from Steam community market

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I've been trying to fetch data from steam community market ,
Code :

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>

static size_t WriteCallback(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

int main(void)
{
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string readBuffer;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?market_hash_name=AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29&appid=730&currency=1");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        std::cout << readBuffer << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But when I run it , nothing show up .
Any help is appreciated ,
Thanks

Comment: Check the result of curl_easy_perform and then check the http-status. After that, a network monitor like wireshark can give more information and you can run the url in the browser with dev-tool (I just checked: the url runs fine in the browser)

Comment: What steps have you done to try and debug it? Does `curl_easy_perform` succeed? Seems like if you're going to capture the return value you should at least check it. Is `WriteCallback` ever called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl` doesn't follow redirects by default, and the site you mention uses those.

I had to turn on `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to make it work:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);  // redirects
// bonus:
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1L); // corp. proxies etc.
```

Possible output:

```
{"success":true,"lowest_price":"$19.00","volume":"477","median_price":"$18.95"}
```

While debugging, you may want this option too to see what `curl` is up to:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
```